# Unable to store Bigint data to mysql database using send_long_data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my mysql database I need to store very large id values.
For that reason I set the type of the field to bigint(11).

When I try to insert values in the table from a prepared mysqli statement in php, all values get set to `2147483647`, which is the highest Integer value in mysql, even though the type of the field is bigint.

For example:

```
echo $id;
$stmt_insert->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt_insert->execute;

if( $stmt_insert === false ) {
    $Logger->error( mysqli_error($conn) );
}
```

Gives me to output `2300679976` but in the database `2147483647` gets stored.

I then read the documentation of the `bind_param` function and found out that for storing large data the `send_long_data` function has to be used. So I tried it the following way:

```
echo $id;
$stmt_insert->bind_param("b", null);
$stmt_insert->send_long_data(0, $id);
$stmt_insert->execute;

if( $stmt_insert === false ) {
    $Logger->error( mysqli_error($conn) );
}
```

But this did not solve the problem. Still `2147483647` is stored even though the table field is set to bigint.

Comment: Thanks for that! Changed it

Comment: Are you positively sure that `$id` contains what you think it does? Please check `var_dump($id)`.

Comment: Thats why I did the echo which gives me `2300679976` as I said. So the `$id` variable is containg the correct value

Comment: Did you see the "User Contributed Notes" in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php ? Might have to set the charset before querying and the max packets.

Comment: AFAIK, `echo` !== `var_dump()` :-?

Comment: hm `var_dump()` gives me `int(2301839148)`

Comment: *"where the type was incorrectly set. I set it to bigint, but accidently with a fixed size of 11, which is the normal int size"* - I had a feeling about that and didn't ask what it was set as. I should've followed my instinct on this one lol - Oh well, glad to see you've solved it. @JakobAbfalter

Comment: @JakobAbfalter Rather than an edit, I feel that you should have posted your own answer and for future visitors to the question. I'd be glad to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the problem was indeed in the mysql database, where the type was incorrectly set.

I did set it to bigint, but accidently with a fixed size of 11, which is the normal int size.

I removed the fixed size and now the field got correctly set to bigint(20) and values are stored correctly now.

Comment: BIGINT only has two possible (fixed) sizes, depending on whether it's signed or unsigned. The number in parenthesis does not have any useful meaning. You had probably defined the column as unsigned INT. It's also worth nothing that you can play with SQL Modes so you can get an error message in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the max int size in MySQL on 32-bit systems is 2147483647, you'll have to change the datatype.  There are a couple of ways to solve this problem.

1. Change the MySQL datatype to double. (the technically correct method)
   Doubles can hold more precision than ints. So one way to handle this is to change your value 2300679976 into a double that looks like 2.300679976 before storing it in the MySQL table.  The catch with this method is that you have to add code to your getters/setters that convert the value to a double going in, and a string coming out.  I call this the 'technically correct method' because it maintains the data as a numeric value.  If you were to move this data to a different database like MsSQL or PostgreSQL, it would stand up to the migration.
2. Change the MySQL datatype to Varchar. (the simple, yet not integris method)
   Varchar gives you room to have ids up to 255 chars long.  This method is simple because it doesn't require you to convert your values as they go in and out of the database.  PHP doesn't care if the value is a string coming out of the database, it will coerce it to a numeric type when you use it in numeric situations anyway.  I call this the 'not integris method' because it's storing the data as a different type than the type that is being used in code, and it's taking advantage of PHPs dynamic typing to automatically make the conversion.  If you were to move this data to a different database, you would likely have some things to fix in your code to get it back to working condition because they are not so lenient when it comes to datatype integrity.